# Finding a Sine Wave That Goes Through a Set of Given Points

Tags: wave-equation, data-analysis

This question is coming from a thought experiment I was having by myself.
Let's say I have 3 random points on a x-y plane (with different x values). Let them be (1,3), (2,5), (5, 1). Is there a sine wave that goes through all 3 of these points, and if there is how would one find it?

I was thinking that:
If we simplify the sine equation by saying it will have a fixed amplitude of 10 and no offset on x or y, giving **y = 10 * sin(x * freq)** then we just need to find "freq". **As the value of freq goes to infinity the sine wave gets closer to going through every point between y = -10 to y = 10.** This gif makes it easy to visualize: [Sine wave as the frequency increases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk5pd.gif)

Does this mean that for any given set of points smaller than the absolute of the amplitude of the sine wave, we can find a frequency such that the sine wave goes through every point? If this is the case would there be a way to find it?

If my reasoning is wrong and it isn't necessarily possible to find such a sine wave just by finding the frequency with fixed amplitude and offsets, is it possible to find a sine wave if we search for not only the frequency but also the amplitude and the offsets on x and y directions?

**TL;dr, my question is:**

Is there always a sine wave $A\times sin((x-j)\times freq)+k$ with $A,freq,j,k \in  \Bbb{N}$, that goes through all the points of a set of points $\\{(x_{0}, y_{0}), (x_{1}, y_{1}), ... , (x_{n}, y_{n})\\}$ with $n\in [0, \infty],$ $x_{i} \ne x_{j}\text{ for all i,j with } i \ne j,$ and $|y_{i}|<|A| \text{ for all } i \in [0, n]$ for any such set? If so, how would one find it?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it: three simultaneous equations $$A \times \sin {freq \times (x_i + k)} = y_i .$$  Three unknowns ($A$, $freq$, and $k$), three equations.  Solve the equations for $x_i$ and $freq$, and see what constraints those solutions put on $A$ (and vice versa).  I think you'll find that there are an infinite number of solutions reachable by increasing $freq$ and/or $A$.  Your reasoning about the density of points reached by increasing $freq$ is good.

Comment: For a single point we have freq = (arcsin(yi/A)+2pi*n)/(xi+k) for some integer n, which gives infinite results, all 2pi apart. We can then write the same equation for all the points and set them equal to each other, and solve for the n, which will then give us the frequency. I'm not sure if it is going to be the same n for all points. Also I wonder if there is a way to find a general equation regardless of the number of points instead of writing a new equation for each point added. Either ways, thank you this cleared a lot for me

Comment: You're kind of asking a new question here: is it possible to find a sine wave that passes through an arbitrary set of N points.  I think you'll find that the answer is "yes". The other part of your question, which asks how much the amplitude and frequency can be constrained and still guarantee a solution, is interesting.  I hope you will explore this further.

Comment: No, my initial question was also about a finding a sine wave that passes through a set of N points.

Comment: I see I misread it.  There is a straightforward way to form a polynomial function that goes through an arbitrary set of points $(x_i, y_i)$, with $x_i \neq x_j$  for any $ i \neq j$.  Maybe an analogous or related approach would work for finding a sine function to pass through a similarly arbitrary set of points.  It would be interesting to develop a formula for fitting a sine wave to three points, then see how the resulting A behaves as one of the points is moved relative to the others.